# Typescript not compiling classes in consistent order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I have an MVC 5 project using TypeScript and angular. I have three TS files: to simplify, we will call them Controller1.ts, Controller2.ts, and app.ts. The problem is that when I launch the program the first time, everything USUALLY (but not always) compiles just fine and in the correct order. However, as soon as I change something and save again to trigger a recompile, it changes the ordering of the classes in the outputted app.js, which causes the contents of app.ts (where the angular app is created) to run before one or both controllers are defined, throwing this error:

```
[ng:areq] Argument 'ProviderScorecardController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Here is how I've defined my app.ts file:

```
/// <reference path="_app.d.ts" />

module mqApp {
'use strict';

    if (typeof (angular) != "undefined") {

        var modules = [];

        angular.module("mqApp", modules)
            .controller("Controller1", Controller1)
            .controller("Controller2", Controller2);
    }
}
```

Both controllers are identical to this except for the class name:

```
/// <reference path="../../_app.d.ts" />

module mqApp {
    'use strict';

    export class Controller1 {
        public static $inject = [
            '$scope'
        ];

        private scope: angular.IScope;

        constructor($scope: angular.IScope) {
            this.scope = $scope;
            console.log("Master Controller Instantiated");
        }
    }
}
```

My _app.d.ts file, which is linked from the above TS file:

```
/// <reference path="_references.d.ts" /> [This just contains angular/jquery references]
/// <reference path="code/controllers/Controller2.ts" />
/// <reference path="code/controllers/Controller1.ts" />
/// <reference path="app.ts" />
```

Changing the order of the references has no effect. What am I doing wrong? Why won't it consistently compile in the correct order?

I am running Angular 1.6 and TypeScript 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is because the compiler tries to build a tree of dependencies between the files but in this case it is circular so the order of compilation might not be what you'd expect.

All of your files reference this one `_app.d.ts` file, meaning that each of the files depend on all the others.
The usage of a single `d.ts` file is good practice when loading libraries (such as what `typings` does) because those libraries don't depend on your source files and so there's no risk of circular dependencies.

In your case it should be:

```
// app.ts file

/// <reference path="./_references.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./code/controllers/Controller1.ts" />
/// <reference path="./code/controllers/Controller2.ts" />

...
```

And:

```
// Controller1.ts

/// <reference path="./_references.d.ts" />

...
```

You can create `d.ts` files that share common needs, but make sure that you don't end up with a circle.

Comment: That was 100% the problem. Thanks! Been scratching my head for a few hours at that. A previous programmer had the same setup in another project, and I copied the structure. Not entirely sure why it worked before.